# WebApi parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am very new to WebApi and don't understand parameters mapping.
I had a controller with HttpGet method with 2 parameters.  In WebApiConfig mapping defined like

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MyActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{p},{q}");
```

which seemed to work fine.

By analogy I've added another controller (DetailsController) that has 3 parameter HttpGet method.

I've added

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MyActionApi2",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{p},{q},{r}");
```

But navigating to

```
http://mysite/api/Details/CrossReport/12,14,Peter
```

gives 404 error and says

> No action was found on the controller 'Details' that matches the request.

But navigating like this

```
http://mysite/api/Details/FilterByDate/12,14?q=10
```

gives correct results.

Why is that?  I'd like to have it comma separated as in the first case.  And why it works in first case but not the second one?

Working controller's method:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> FilterByDate(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd).
```

Not working:

```
public IEnumerable<Detail> FilterByDate(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd, int maxCount)
```

Both have HttpGet attribute.

Comment: please post your action signatures

Comment: one of your examples is for FilterByDate action and the other (not working) is for crossReport - what does the crossReport method on the controller look like ?

Comment: @Nickolodeon Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a matching action. Try adding an action with the following signature on your DetailsController class:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Detail> CrossReport(string p, string q, string r)
```

As you see, the action name and parameter names must match what you have on your route.

Comment: Actually I did (see updated question).  But it's not working in a way described, that is in 404 way.

Comment: @Nickolodeon - I can't see a method CrossReport in your post - you've created just the FilterByDate actions

Comment: CrossReport action signature is identical to FilterByDate.

Comment: Well, for now ? will be used for the 3rd param.  Later I'll read some more tutorials on this routing stuff and hopefully won't have such stupid problems anymore.  Thanks to all for participating.

Answer (score 1):

One thought, have you made sure that MyActionApi2 ahead of MyActionApi in you routing config?  If I am not mistaken, It looks for the first possible match... and so MyActionApi would match (even if there are 3 parameters)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of parameters in WebApi: parameters in routes and parameters in body/url.

### Parameter in route

In this example the id param is in the route.

```
http://mysite/api/Details/CrossReport/{id}
```

The route params are separate by "/" and there are part of the route.

```
http://mysite/api/Details/CrossReport/{id}/{name}/{detailId}
```

In your web api controller you must be:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> FilterByDate(int id, string name, int detailId)
```

### Parameter in body/url

The parameters in url are separate by & and all this params are after a ? in route. For example.

```
http://mysite/api/Details/CrossReport?id=3&name="john"&detailId=5
```

And in your web api controller is the same:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> FilterByDate(int id, string name, int detailId)
```

If the object is compound by others properties:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can only have one in the body of the message and you have to send in the body on the message and your web api controller receipt them:

```
public IEnumerable<Order> FilterByDate(MyObject obj)
```